# Web Service from WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services

In my project i have to call a web service(.net) from a WCF service. I am getting some runtime errors while doing the same, please tell my how to achieve the same so that i can check, what is missing in my approach.

Hi,

The code in WCF looks like this(sample code)

```
 public int AddWCF(int a, int b)
        {
            proxy_http.CalculatorSoapClient ad = new proxy_http.CalculatorSoapClient("CalculatorSoap");
            int ab = ad.Add(a,b);  
            return ab;
        }
```

The one in web service looks like this :-

```
public Calculator () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }
    [WebMethod(Description = "This method can be used to Add 2 integers", MessageName = "AddMethod")]
    public int Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    [WebMethod(Description = "This method can be used to Subtract 2 integers", MessageName = "SubtractMethod")]
    public int Subtract(int num1, int num2)
    {        
            return num1 - num2;        
    }
```

The error occurs in the WCF part where instance of web service is created, following error is given when

“Could not find endpoint element with name 'CalculatorSoap' and contract 'proxy_http.CalculatorSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.”

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are doing it ? Post some code, details about the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message suggests that it couldn't find any Endpoint in configuration file with name `CalculatorSoap` implementing contract `proxy_http.CalculatorSoapClient`.

Please check your configuration file (web.config in case your WCF service is webhosted), whether it has endpoint with the name `CalculatorSoap` under **<`client`>** section of <`system.serviceModel`> implementing `proxy_http.CalculatorSoapClient`.

Please note the names are case-sensitive.